# How to compile projects from 2.3 to 4.0?

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

Recently, I was asked to compile some of my Android projects, based on the 2.3, for the new 4.0 versions. So without much knowledge on how to do it, I simply tried to do it myself by making a few changes in the manifest file like the `min SDK` and `targeted SDK`. I set the `min SDK` to **10** and `targeted SDK` to **15**. Hoping that would somehow work, I test run my codes only to see that it doesn't work out the way I hope. Of course, it works really well on the 2.3, both on simulator and device.

Is there a way to upgrade / convert this project to compile and build with the latest version other that redoing it? Can anyone help?

**EDIT 1:**
After hours of troubleshooting, and searching for online clues. I decided to look this a little more deeper. I found out that this line:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url11);
HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(get); // 4.0.3 crashes here....
```

Was the cause of the problem. Now I ran the AVD Manager from 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 to test out this problem , and it turns out that this line runs smoothly with no errors on the 2.3.3. Could there be a deprecation or something in the new 4.0.3?

Comment: Android applications are generally forward-compatible. Can you describe the unexpected behavior?

Comment: I get no output, some of my static `TextView` texts starts disappearing during runtime. That is what I seen despite having the app to run for 5-10mins hoping that it could be due to the internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's caused by performing network operations on main thread.

It causes [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) when the targetSdkVersion is 11 or higher on AndroidManifest.xml.

Move it to the background thread using AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader.